# After reaching a large MySQL DB (say 1 mil rows) does providing LIMIT help optimizations?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I'm using PHP 7, MySQL and a small custom-built forum and a query for grabbing 7 columns with 2 SQL join statements into a "latest post" page. When the time comes that I hit 1 million rows will the limit 30 stop at 30 rows or will it have to sort the entire DB each run?

The reason I'm asking is I'm trying to wrap my head around how to paginate this custom forum I've built and if that pagination will be "ok" once it has to (theoretically) read through a million rows?

EDIT: My current query is a limit 30, sort desc.

EDIT2: Currently I'm getting about 500-600 posts give or take 50 a day. It's quickly adding up so I'm trying to monitor this before I get 1 million. That being said I'm only looking up one table right now, `tblTopics` and topic_id, topic_name, and topic_author (a fk). Then I'm doing another another lookup after that with the topic itself's foreign keys, topic_rating, and topic_category. The original lookup is where I have the sort and limit.

Comment: You are looking for latest posts.  Can you provide a little more context to your web site?  Trying to return and paginate 1M rows appears absurd when you might offer more drilled down offering.  We can't really offer a better option without context, what is searched for, presented, etc.

Comment: See that's what I'm afraid of. Since it's a complete home-brewed situation I'm looking for any better SQL entries maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Sort is applied on the complete set, limit is applied after the sort, so adding a limit to an `ORDER BY` query does not make it a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering more on the LIMIT aspect. As my page needs to lookup the latest forum posts with a (theoretical) 1 million rows I'm considering the best avenue of approach for this.

Comment: `LIMIT` will stop selecting, if an index can completely cover your `where` and `order by` clauses.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Nice, so for example a `whereid=x order by date desc limit 30` would stop the process at 30? (I'm starting to get fearful thinking of that load on every single user on that page on a million row dataset lol.)

Comment: `order by .. desc` might be a problem if you use `where` - but i'm not sure. Please read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: The official docs...of course! :) I should have thought of that in the first place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

```
SELECT ... FROM tbl ORDER BY x LIMIT 30;
INDEX(x)
```

will *probably* use the index and stop after 30 rows, not 1 million.

```
SELECT ... FROM tbl GROUP BY zz ORDER BY x LIMIT 30;
```

will scan all million rows, do the grouping, write to a tmp table, sort that tmp table, and only then deliver 30 rows.

```
SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE yy = 123 ORDER BY x LIMIT 30;
INDEX(yy)
```

will probably prefer `INDEX(yy)`, and it is hard to say how efficient it will be.

```
SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE yy = 123 ORDER BY x LIMIT 30;
INDEX(yy, x)
```

will be very efficient -- not only can it use the index for filtering, but also for the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT`.  Only 30 rows will be touched.

```
SELECT ... FROM tbl LIMIT 30;
```

is of dubious use.  You will get *some* 30 rows, but who knows which 30?  But it will be fast.

Well, this is still not answering you question.  Your question involves a `JOIN`.  Can you guess how much more complex the question becomes with `JOIN` involved?

If you would like to discuss your *specific* query, please provide the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table and how many rows in each table.

If you are joining a 1-row table to a million row table, the 1-row table probably does not add any complexity.

If you are joining two million-row tables together without any indexes, then you are looking at a *trillion* intermediate 'rows' to work with!

Oh, and then you will want the 'second' 30 rows?  That adds another dimension of complexity.  I could spend a few more paragraphs on what can go wrong with `OFFSET`.

Answer (score 0):

If this forum is somewhat open-ended where anyone can post "topics" and be the originating author, you probably want at a minimum a topics table with a PKID, Name, Author as you have, but also date added and most recent post and also count of posts against it.  Too many times people build web sites that want counters all over the place and try to do aggregates, or the most recent, etc.  Come to mention the most recent post, hold the ID of the most recent post too so you don't have to find the max date, then get the join base on that.

Then secondary table would be the details associated for a given post.

Then, via a trigger on your detail table for whatever you are posting against, you can do an update to the parent topic id and stamp it with count +1, most recent date of now, and the last ID with the ID of the newest record just created.

So now, joining to get that most recent context entry is a simple join and not overly complex.

Index on your topics table on the most recent post date so you are now getting ex: the most recent 30 topics, not necessarily the most recent 30 posts, such as 3 posts have a bunch of hits and account for all 30.  Get 30 distinct topics, then let user see the details as they select the topic of interest.  Your query at the top level is never going against the underlying details.

Obviously brief on true context of your website, but hopefully suggestions make sense for you to run with.

Comment: Thanks. As it's a niche forum/community right now everything from the top to bottom is home brewed so just making sure I nick and tuck the best I can.